how to write a std out to a unique temporary file name and use the same to mail out
I have a script that works as expected. It basically runs a bunch of other scripts and redirects the output to a file, once every part is done, I mail the output file and delete the same. In recent times, i am trying to run a second instance of this script to make it faster by running it on another session, Here the second instance clashes with the output file of the first instance. since the output filename is same, it gets either overwritten, or tries to write but the first instance already deleted the file. I hope you understand.
sample below
ssh $i '/usr/local/bin/script1'| tee ~/script1.txt
echo
sleep 2
mail -s "script" `whoami`@xxx.com < ~/script1.txt
sleep 2
rm scripts1.txt
script2 -f inputfile | tee ~/script2.txt
echo
mail -s "scritp2" `whoami`@xxx.com < ~/script2.txt
rm script2

so I am thinking of redirecting the output to random or temp file name, so the newer instance of the script doesnt interfere with the output file and has a unique output file.

man 1 mktemp, also there are a number of issues with your code, including, but not limited to, deprecated backticks and using sleep(1) to try circumventing race conditions (it doesn't solve that problem).

my 2 cents:  on (almost?) all Unix/Linux systems the current shell PID is identified by the expression $$  -> i.e. in your script you may define the name of a temp file based on it, for example as
/tmp/my_temp_log--$$.txt
and you are (almost) sure this file is uniquely written by each specific shell instance running that script

@sigmud, and that's very unsafe as that file path is predictable and created here in a world-writable directory (/tmp). See also "Traditionally, many shell scripts take the name of the program with the pid as a suffix and use that as a temporary file name"

You don't need a temp file here, you can just use a pipe:
ssh "$host" '/usr/local/bin/script1' |
  mail -s script "$LOGNAME@xxx.com"

Or if you want to also print the output to stdout, with zsh:
{
  ssh $host '/usr/local/bin/script1' >&3 |
    mail -s script $USERNAME@xxx.com
} 3>&1

With shells with support for ksh-style process substitution (ksh, zsh, bash):
ssh $host '/usr/local/bin/script1' |
  tee -- >(mail -s script $LOGNAME@xxx.com)

(bear in mind that in some shells such as bash, mail is not waited for, so the next command could be started before the mail is sent).
To create unique temp files, most systems have a mktemp command for that:
tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
ssh "$host" '/usr/local/bin/script1' |
  tee -- "$tmp"
echo
sleep 2
<"$tmp" mail -s script "$LOGNAME@xxx.com"
rm -f -- "$tmp"

In zsh, you can use the =(...) form of process substitution which uses a temp file that is automatically deleted after the command that uses it terminates. Here that command could be a for loop looping on an empty =(...):
for tmp ( =() ) {
  ssh $host '/usr/local/bin/script1' >&1 > $tmp
  echo
  sleep 2
  <$tmp mail -s script $USERNAME@xxx.com
}

